# Missing examples for Visual C++ compiler warnings

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, static-code-analysis

I cannot figure out under what circumstances these two compiler warnings would be indicated:

[C28206](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c28206):

> <expression> : left operand points to a struct, use ->
>
> This warning is reported when the struct pointer dereference notation -> was expected.

[C28207](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c28207):

> <expression>: left operand is a struct, use .
>
> This warning is reported when a struct dereference dot (.) was expected.

Could someone please provide examples?

I tried the following examples. The code analysis was carried out using the [Native Recommended Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/native-recommended-rules-rule-set) ruleset (which includes both warnings) and with warning level `/Wall` (all warnings enabled).

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    int value;
};
```

```
SomeStruct* foo = new SomeStruct();
(*foo).value = 2; // Would have expected C28206 to be detected here.
```

```
SomeStruct foo = SomeStruct();
(&foo)->value = 2; // Would have expected C28207 to be detected here.
```

Other warnings are detected (e.g. [C6001](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6001)):

```
SomeStruct foobar()
{
    SomeStruct foo;
    return foo; // C6001 is detected here.
}
```